# Equivalent of PHP gmdate

Tags: javascript, node.js, date, date-format

I'm trying to sign an Amazon request and I need the following timestamp format:

```
gmdate('Y-m-d\TH:i:s\Z');
```

How can I obtain that in a nodejs environment? Many thanks in advance.

Comment: [MomentJS](https://momentjs.com/) is one of the most popular JS libraries for date-time manipulation.

Comment: You should provide an example of the format you require, there is little consistency for tokens used in date and time format strings.

Comment: Probably a duplicate of [*Where can I find documentation on formatting a date in JavaScript?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056728/where-can-i-find-documentation-on-formatting-a-date-in-javascript)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For anyone who will need this:

```
new Date().toISOString()
```